# Converting SVG into Raster PNGs by Android Studio

Tags: android, svg, vector, material-design

I am working with Android Studio 2.2.2. I am developing a project and it will be used in Tab 7 inch.
I am importing SVG through vector asset wizard. My tablet, where I am compiling the APK is 7-inch. After installation, the application showing the SVGs in very bad quality.
I made several types of research and concluded that my Tablet is having API-19 and android studio is converting all SVGs into the Raster PNGs (For all devices below V-21) at compile time and place them on the following path

D:....\app\build\generated\res\pngs\debug

When I looked at this folder I found 
[image]

I know for 7-inch Tablet drawable-large-mdpi or drawable-large-hdpi is required, because android studio is not creating the drawable folder for larger screens and placing the Raster PNGs into smal screens drawable folder, That's may be the reason of bad quality of SVGs because 7-inch tablet is using the PNG from drawable-mdpi which is made for small screens.

Can anyone advice how to force Android-Studio to create drawable-large-mdpi folder under app\build\generated\res\pngs\debug and place the converted Raster PNG into it.

Comment: Why would you ever want to use PNGs, if you have a much lighter SVG, which is - by definition - **scalable**?

Comment: Brother i mentioned that i am using V-19 Tablet. SVGs are supported from v-21. and for all older versions android studio is converting the SVG into Raster-PNGs

Comment: **SVGs are NOT supported by Android at all**. You mean *VectorDrawables*, which are a **limited subset of the SVG format**. For that, you can use the **support libraries**. OR use a SVG library to read **real SVG files**.

Comment: For further clarification, I am using SVGs. Android studio is converting them into Raster-PNG because my tablet having API-LEVEL-19. But the problem is under generated/pngs android studio is not creating the larger-drawable forlder. thats why application showing bad-quality of pngs.

Comment: Please re-read my previous comment. You are not using SVGs at all. You are using their PNG conversions. You may use a freeware such as InkScape and do that manually, if that is your goal. But the real point is... use VECTORS instead of BITMAPS. With all the advantages that this implies.

Comment: See what I am exactly doing. I am downloading the icon from https://www.flaticon.com in SVG format. then i am importing it through vector-asset by right clicking on drawable folders. That's all. when I am compiling the build. The imported vector is not showing in good resolution so I found that there is no drawable-large-mdpi folder under the generated PNGs.

Comment: `I am downloading the icon from flaticon.com in svg format. then i am importing it throug vector-asset by right clicking on drawable forlders.` **WHY??**. If you use an SVG library to read the SVG file DIRECTLY, it would scale perfectly. And you wouldn't need to pass through vector-asset. OR convert the SVG file to a VectorDrawable and use the **support library** to access the VectorDrawables on **any** Android version.